# html email template hairlines

Tags: html-email, email-templates

I have an email template with different block background colors, and because of this the colors are bleeding and creating lines between the blocks
I tried all the solutions I found and nothing worked, and after hours of digging I think the problem is that the nested tables are slightly shorter than their parent tables

here you can see the problem and what I mean by slightly shorter (the orange is showing and the white is within it, if it was the same height no orange will be showing):
[image]

and this is the code for one of the blocks:

```
<div>
      <table
        align="center"
        border="0"
        cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="0"
        style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background:{$cordial-variable}; border-collapse: collapse;"
        bgcolor="{$cordial-variable}"
        width="100%"
      >
        <tr>
          <td align="center" valign="top">
            <table
              width="700"
              bgcolor="#fcfcfc"
              border="0"
              cellspacing="0"
              cellpadding="0"
              style="
                mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                padding: 0;
              "
            >
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                  <div>
                    <table
                      width="600"
                      border="0"
                      cellspacing="0"
                      cellpadding="0"
                      style="
                        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
                        border-collapse: collapse;
                        border: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        width: 80%;
                        height: auto;
                      "
                    >
                      <tr>
                        <td style="35px" height="35"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

the things I tried: setting background color for all tables and tds, setting valign for all trs, changing the heights to even values instead of odd ones, setting the images with 0 line-height and font-size, setting the height to 100% instead of auto.

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To get a block a specific height, cross email compatible, you need only this:

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding:35px 0 0 0;font-size:0;line-height: 0;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Note the `&nbsp;` which you don't have--some email clients will add that in and then use a default font-size or line-height on it.

The first `<table>` you have is fine: cellpadding, cellspacing and border are zeroed and that should be enough.

`<div>s` are not needed.